# windows 2003 server policy error

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

i saw these two errors on my windows 2003 server from last few days

can you please tell me what is these errors and how to remove them

[image]

[image]

Comment: hm

alt text?

May I suggest you actually put the proper error messages in there?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when group policy trys to process group policy, before other components are ready. There was a fix for this in a service pack for server 2003, what SP are you running?

Comment: i am using service Pack 2 v2845

Answer (score 0):

Use the script c:\program files\GPMC\Scripts\DumpGPOInfo.wsf to get the name of the offending GPO:

cscript DumpGPOInfo.wsf {guid from error}

Will give the name of the offending GPO.  i.e. set screensaver.

Go to the Group Policy Management Console and attempt to edit the offending GPO. It sounds like you will recieve "unable to locate file", delete the GPO, run GPUdate /force and the 1058/1030 should go away. Then recreated the original GPO.